# How to change text and function of a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery js below hides the content before a link I placed. Upon clicking it will show. I want to change the text from "Show Crisis" to "Hide Crisis" and the function from .show() to .hide(). I'm not sure how I can go ahead doing this so some help would be great!

JS:

```
$(".crisisButtons").hide().before("<a href='#' class='showHide'>Show Crisis</a>");
      $(".showHide").click(function(){
            var link = $(this);
            link.next().show("slow");
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method's callback function.

```
$(".showHide").click(function(){
    $(this).text(function(_, text){
         return text === 'Show Crisis' ? 'Hide Crisis' : 'Show Crisis';
    }).next().toggle("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kNBwD/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#youratag_id").text("Show crisis");
```

Should be as simple as that

Or using toggle:

```
$(function() {
        $(".showHide").toggle(function (){
            $(this).text("Show crisis");
            .stop();
        }, function(){
            $(this).text("Hide crisis");
            .stop();
        });
    });
```

Comment: `toggle` event method is deprecated and has been removed as of jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something of this sort:

```
button.click(function () {
    link.toggle('fast', function () {
        button.text(link.css('display') === 'none' ? 'Show Crisis' : 'Hide Crisis'));
    });
});
```